# Invalid Bundle - A nested bundle doesn't have the right platforms listed in CFBundleSupportedPlatforms Info.plist key

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I uploaded an app to the `iOS` App Store `testflight`.

I received the following email in response from iOS App Store:

> *Invalid Bundle - A nested bundle doesn't have the right platforms listed in CFBundleSupportedPlatforms Info.plist key. Once these issues
>   have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.*

What should I do to resolve this and get my App approved?

Comment: Same here... I even don't have this key inside my info.plist file

Comment: Same here also , can any one suggest ??

Comment: Same here. Neither setting `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` per bundle nor removing it has any effect.

Comment: Are you using Google maps framework ?

Comment: Can't speak for the TS, but I am not

Comment: We found the offending entry in our google maps dependency.  Removing the entry from the maps plist solved the issue for us.

Comment: Same issue here. @ngatirauks: Is there an any list of offending keys which needs to remove? I am using google maps.

Answer (score 0):

Archiving and submitting my app with older xcode version (6.3.1) solved the problem for me. I think it's xcode 7 bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here, I solve it by searching for key CFBundleSupportedPlatforms and delete it from any info.plist file I found.
using Xcode 7.0.1

update: After I fixed this error I uploaded new binary and it got finish the processing right away, and the old binary (with Invalid Bundle error) still processing until now.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to Xcode7.1 and I'm no longer receiving any of those `Invalid Bundle` emails from iTunes connect. Beforehand I contacted apple and they verified there was nothing wrong with the IPA:

> I’ve looked at your IPA, and there is nothing that I see which will
>   cause a CFBundleSupportedPlatforms error as you are seeing.
>
> Could you please try uploading your app one more time to see if it still fails? It’s possible iTunes Connect had an intermittent problem in validating your app.
>
> If this upload still fails, please let me know.  The next step will be for me to escalate this to iTunes Connect to understand why your app is failing validation.  This step can take some time, which is why I want to rule out an intermittent problem first.

After that mail I retried by creating a new archive in Xcode7.1 and uploading it to the app store. And all went well

Answer (score 0):

Some plist file in your app (it could be also a framework's file) has CFBundleSupportedPlatforms key with wrong value. You should find it and change it to "iPhoneOS". To do it you could use a `grep` command. Open Terminal and run:

```
grep -r "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms" /YourProjectPathHere
```

It will show you all files that have a `CFBundleSupportedPlatforms` string